# Is the derelict vessel in 'Aliens' an Engineer ship?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

Is the area with all the xenomorphs in the missing derelict in the same place as on an Engineer ship? I thought they might be the same because it has the big gun-like star map found in Prometheus.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm assuming (from the title) that you're asking if the ship in Aliens is an Engineer vessel but I'm at a loss what the rest of your question is driving at.

Comment: Poor quality question, however I do get what you're saying.

Comment: @Mooz Maybe you could edit it to make it clearer then? I'm with Richard here - can't understand it.

Comment: Also, I think the OP is referring to either a video game with a mission called "derelict", or the first movie (*Alien*), not the second movie (*Aliens*).

Comment: @WadCheber - The OP tagged it as "aliens". It's also worth noting that the crashed ship in Alien and Aliens is the same vessel.

Comment: hi what i ment was from aliens:colonial marines sorry for late comment

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the [derelict ship](http://alienanthology.wikia.com/wiki/The_Derelict) on the surface of LV-426 (in Aliens) is indeed an Engineer ship. In the film "Prometheus" and its accompanying literature, we learn that these types of ship were part of a entire *class* of vessels known as "[Juggernauts](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernaut)" which the Engineer race used to explore the galaxy.

Several near-identical vessels are seen in Prometheus, along with the one that the titular ship rams.